# Not fetching all images from json

Tags: android, json

I have two images in JSONArray. First is an image and other is thumbnail of a video. The thumbnail is showing but the image does not appears. I'm unable to understand what's the problem. I would be pleased to have any help to properly fetch the json.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GridView mGridView;
    private GridItem newItem;
    private GridViewAdapter mGridAdapter;
    private ArrayList<GridItem> mGridData;
    public static final String KEY_USERID = "user_id";
    private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8001/api/userlog/fetch/";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        registerUser();

        mGridData = new ArrayList<>();

       mGridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.profile_gridview_item, mGridData);
        mGridView.setAdapter(mGridAdapter);




    }

/////////////////////////////////////////  Volley Method Starts //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    private void registerUser(){

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);

                            System.out.println(jObj);

                            String status = jObj.getString("status");

                            // Now check status value
                            if (status.equals("0")) {

                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "There was some error! Please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            }else if(status.equals("1")){



                                JSONArray result = jObj.getJSONArray("results");

                                for(int i = 0 ; i <result.length() ; i++){
                                    JSONObject json_data = result.getJSONObject(i);

                                    newItem = new GridItem();

                                        String image = json_data.getString("log_file");
                                        String date = json_data.getString("create_day");
                                        String month = json_data.getString("create_month");

                                        newItem.setImage(image);
                                        newItem.setDate(date);
                                        newItem.setMonth(month);
                                        mGridData.add(newItem);


                                }

                                mGridAdapter.setGridData(mGridData);

                            } else {
                                // Error in login. Get the error message
                                String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // JSON error
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }



                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_USERID, "1");
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////  Volley Method Ends ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



}
```

Comment: Put your json response from jsonlint

Comment: http://www.hastebin.com/lakemavoga.apache

Comment: try `mGridAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` method after `for(int i = 0 ; i <result.length() ; i++){` this loop..

Comment: also add `Log.d("Response", "RESPONSE :: " + jObj);` line after `JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);` and check if it returns correct object.

Comment: My Adapter has notifyDataSetChanged(); http://www.hastebin.com/subejupezu.avrasm @ELITE

Comment: then change the location of `mGridAdapter.setGridData(mGridData);` after `for` loop...

Comment: That's Log of jObj http://www.hastebin.com/zonimerase.md

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104699/discussion-between-sam-and-elite).